# Is there a way to install a private key for a user with cloud-init?

Tags: terraform, ssh, terraform-module, cloud-init

I have a user that needs to authenticate against a company source repository when using `git clone`. To set this up for the user I need to specify a users private key (not the host private key in `/etc`). Is there a method to do this?

The user it configured with [`system_info` in cloud-init](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/examples.html?highlight=system_info#including-users-and-groups), which doesn't have a mechanism to install the user's private key.

Note: Let's say you're provisioning a a new machine and adding a user bob on it. How do you install a private key for a bob such that he can authenticate with something using ssh?

Comment: there are many ways to do this, but it's hard to answer this question without knowing the constraints. Can you give some more context to help give a more appropriate answer?

Comment: I've self-answered this, as promised. ;) That was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Update

Oops, **Don't do this**. It was pointed out to me that this was wholly insecure as `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data` will show you any unprivileged user the private keys. The data gets saved as `/run/cloud-init/instance-data.json`

## Original post

There is no module to make this easier, and there is no argument under `system_info` (how you add and configure the user) to ease the ability to configure the user's SSH keys. The way I went about this was adding something like this in my `main.tf` to populate the variable `ssh_keys_user`

```json
ssh_keys_user = {
  write_files = [
    {
      path        = "/home/ecarroll/.ssh/id_rsa"
      content     = file("./ssh/user/cp-terraform-user-id_rsa")
      owner       = "ecarroll:ecarroll"
      permissions = "0600"
      defer       = true
    },
    {
      path        = "/home/ecarroll/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
      content     = file("./ssh/user/cp-terraform-user-id_rsa.pub")
      owner       = "ecarroll:ecarroll"
      permissions = "0644"
      defer       = true
    },
    {
      path        = "/home/ecarroll/.ssh/id_ecdsa"
      content     = file("./ssh/user/cp-terraform-user-id_ecdsa")
      owner       = "ecarroll:ecarroll"
      permissions = "0600"
      defer       = true
    },
    {
      path        = "/home/ecarroll/.ssh/id_ecdsa.pub"
      content     = file("./ssh/user/cp-terraform-user-id_ecdsa.pub")
      owner       = "ecarroll:ecarroll"
      permissions = "0644"
      defer       = true
    },
    {
      path        = "/home/ecarroll/.ssh/id_ed25519"
      content     = file("./ssh/user/cp-terraform-user-id_ed25519")
      owner       = "ecarroll:ecarroll"
      permissions = "0600"
      defer       = true
    },
    {
      path        = "/home/ecarroll/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub"
      content     = file("./ssh/user/cp-terraform-user-id_ed25519.pub")
      owner       = "ecarroll:ecarroll"
      permissions = "0644"
      defer       = true
    }
  ]
}
```

Then what I did was wired it into my cloud-init like this,

```yaml
write_files:
${ yamlencode( ssh_keys_user.write_files ) }
```

I generated these files with a Makefile like this,

```
user/cp-terraform-user-id_ecdsa:
        -mkdir user 2> /dev/null;
        ssh-keygen -C "User key for SSH authentication to repos" -N "" -b 521 -t ecdsa -f "$@";
        touch "$@";

user/cp-terraform-user-id_ed25519:
        -mkdir user 2> /dev/null;
        ssh-keygen -C "User key for SSH authentication to repos" -N "" -t ed25519 -f "$@";
        touch "$@";

user/cp-terraform-user-id_rsa:
        -mkdir user 2> /dev/null;
        ssh-keygen -C "User key for SSH authentication to repos" -N "" -b 4096 -t rsa -f "$@";
        touch "$@";
```

This works fine. Then I just added the `.pub` files to BitBucket and GitLab.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the keys being generated on boot, you could potentially use the phone-home module to send the newly generated pubkeys wherever you need them to go:

The current example for [this module](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html#phone-home) might be a good starting point.

```
    url: http://example.com/$INSTANCE_ID/
    post:
        - pub_key_dsa
        - pub_key_rsa
        - pub_key_ecdsa
        - pub_key_ed25519
        - instance_id
        - hostname
        - fqdn
    tries: 5
```

I haven't done this before, but if "keys generated on boot" fits your requirements, something like this *should* work.