# Is there a way to pass secrets in cloud-init using Terraform?

Tags: terraform, cloud-init

Cloud-init has the ability to compliment Terraform in configuring the Virtual Machine it just created. My problem is that cloud-init as uploaded through `user-data` means that the script especially if multi-part is available on the OpenStack metadata server.

This means *any* user on that virtual machine can get that user-data by simply running

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data
```

Is there anyway to pass secrets in a cloud-init file?

---

This is a follow up to [*"Is there a way to install a private key for a user with cloud-init?"*](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/15628/18965). There I ask a question which could conceivably be answered with a provisioner that doesn't use cloud-init at all. This question is more broad.

Answer (score 0):

> This means any user on that virtual machine can get that user-data by simply running
>
> > curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data

Correct

> Is there anyway to pass secrets in a cloud-init file?

Some ideas to consider:

- add a firewall rule at the end of initialization to limit access to `169.254.169.254`
- include a private key in the base image that can be used to decrypt encrypted content which is written via `write-files` or `runcmd` / `bootcmd`
- include the secret directly in the base image, or via a drive that is attached during provisioning